# React Native - FlatList not invoking renderItem's lifecycle methods on refresh

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to make a fetch request inside `renderItem`'s `componentDidMount` method every time the list is refreshed, but the `FlatList` calls the lifecycle methods only once.

The list

```
<FlatList data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem imageHref={item.imageHref} />}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={/* Fetching data from JSON and updating dataSource[] */} />
```

Inside `ListItem` component:

```
render() {
    return <Image source={this.state.imageSource} />
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.props.imageHref)
        .then(response => {
            if(response.status !== 200)
                this.setState({imageSource: require('../assets/default-image.png')
            else
                this.setState({imageSource: {uri: this.props.imageHref}});
            }
        });
}
```

I tried calling `fetch` inside `render` method but that didn't work either.

I basically want the `imageSource` to update every time the list is refreshed. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Because of that `ListItem` was not change. You have to fetch new icon in `onRefresh` and pass it into `ListItem` then all data will be changed when ListView will refresh... if you want to do it inside `ListItem` you need some interaction with that specific item, for example, some button and if user press it fetch and change icon

Comment: No, that's not it. I changed JSON data multiple times and refreshed but it never called componentDidMount more than once.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't know when your list refreshed , but you can try this `this.forceUpdate()` you can learn more here [force component to re render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)